# Usage of the Particle で alone and with は

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-で

I understand what the particle で does as far as describing how or where an action took place.  But I notice that I run into で many other times where it seems to have a different function.

Could someone help clarify the uses of で?  Specifically its uses other than describing how/where an action occurred.

An example would be something like this:

> 必ず届くこのいっしゅんのひかりで

Or as used in では, or じゃ.  I know what it means in conjugations for adjectives and such, but I often see just では following other words like nouns with no verb after it or any thing.  In the case where it's alone like that, what does it mean?

Comment: There are many ways で can be used. Do you have a specific example in mind? Otherwise the question is very broad.

Comment: Sure, I'll update it with an example.

Comment: But that's still exactly how/where the action occurred...

Comment: I want to note that で is not always particle. Sometimes it's te-form of だ. I'm not sure if this is consensus or there is different point of views, but from sources where I seen it で in ではない is also te-form of だ.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that.  Thanks!  That does beget another question though.   I can't think of any time I've seen it used outside of things like ではありません/じゃありません/etc.  Could you give me an example/situation using the て form of だ/です outside of the uses I already mentioned?

Comment: Haha @Leebo, just saw your name.  I'd be willing to bet anything that you're the same Leebo who answers my questions on WaniKani's forum all the time ;)    ひさしぶり！！